# Neutral 14 ga wires hot

Tags: electrical, wiring

I just replaced my 15 amp outlet with a new decora 15 amp receptacle. I noticed even before disconnecting all of the 14 ga copper wires that when I tested each neutral wire that two neutrals were hot.

Originally they had two neutrals wired nut together with a hook to the receptacle coming from one of the conduits. The other neutral came from another location.  Even after resembling it and test it with the sperry stop shock it was green or wired correctly.

Why are these neutrals hot and if so should i separated the hot and wired nut those? I didn't use a voltage meter which maybe i should had. I did us a Klein non-contact tester. Again this was the original wiring from 40 yrs ago. Suggestions would be appreciated.  I also replaced all of the wire nuts and cut and stripped away copper wire as well as adding some new wiring.

UPDATE: I took it all apart the 14 ga wire from the receptacle. there are only two conduit s that feed into this box conduit 1 and conduit 2. (See all pictures below.)

I then took my voltage meter and check each white neutral wire with my klein clamp meter alligator ears which showed zero except for one voltage reading of white with a black mark on neutral wire which was only a small or negligible reading. The blue wire in the back was for a split connection and was never wired up. Put everything originally back with only one hot black wire i mark with red tape.

Saying all of this, i noticed that if i disconnect the one neutral with the black mark all of my receptacles/outlets that are controlled by that 15 amp are turned off. Why? Why not that one to be off while the other receptacles should just be turned on.  Why are the rest not working? Yes the sperry stop shock test works perfectly on this receptacle. Also used a breaker finder to see which two wires are truly connected to thar one 15 amp.

If that was run in a series could that be an explanation of when i disconnect that white neutral -black mark can cause 20 receptacles/outlets to shut off? Would appreciate the help. How could this happen? Yes it works and as i mentioned earlier in another question about adding another amp to split this 20 receptacles/fixtures/switches.

On second thought, i think this also happened with any outlet that i replaced with none of then working. Would have to double check that fact. Again i didnt do anything different but to replace the receptacles and switches as they had it originally wired. Thank you again.

[image: apart]

[image: conduit 1]

[image: meter]

[image: bllue wires]

[image: white wire black marking]

[image: final connections]

Comment: If the receptacle is connected, plug in a tester and see what the test lights' tell you. To make sure those neutrals are truly hot use a voltmeter and test them to ground.

Comment: Isherwood is right about the picture --will correct. Jim i will test this with a voltmeter. But if does have truly voltage in one of those neutrals what do you normally do? And why did the sperry stop shocker show green (wiring is correct) or why diid  the non contact tester showed neutrals hot?  Regardless, Will get back to it in a few days and let you know the results with a clearer picture and the results with the voltmeter. Real Bad back and had and this receptacle is behind a huge bookcase; otherwise i would do it tomorrow. I did notice that one of the neutrals had black markings on it!!

Comment: Larry, I think you should trust the "Sperry Stop Shocker" especially if the wiring seems to be working correctly to the extent of not tripping breakers, and lights and other receptacles on the same circuit are apparently functioning properly.  I have had trouble with a non-contact tester showing hot when a wire could not possibly be hot. Probably I was getting it too close to a truly hot wire.

Comment: It had worked fir 4o years before, but to play it on the safe side i will test the white neutrals for safety and learning experience? Again thanks

Comment: Larry, the excellent pictures should now allow the experienced and capable electrical workers on this site to figure out what you have. You have plenty of good looking copper conductor. (It's AL NM in our house!) My thought is that you *may* have had one receptacle of the pair controlled by a switch and the other always on. On the duplex receptacle you removed were the side tabs broken off? One problem is going to be box fill. There is a lot of wire and it looks like a small box. Is this individual wires pulled through rigid steel conduit? Or is this the flexible armored cable?

Comment: Those WAGO connectors are a good choice, I think, because (1) they have a probe hole to allow voltage testing when they are connected and in use. (2) you can connect or disconnect one wire at a time.  However, once you have it all figured out and working you might not be able to fold and pack all this into the box.  You might have to use a combination of side screws and back connections to be able fit all this into this box. Or you might need a metal box extension or some box extender which *does not occupy space inside the box*. There are extenders like that for metal boxes.

Comment: Larry, if the wiring worked for 40 years, but is not working after you changed the duplex receptacle, then, almost certainly, you did not reconnect it *exactly* as it had been. You *thought* you were connecting it the same way, but you must have missed something and it's now connected differently. Keep the old receptacles for any one that you change and identify each one as to its location. It would also be a good idea to take a picture before you disconnect.

Comment: @JimStewart Will take it before. Found receptacle with both tabs  attached.  found the receptacle - both tabs top and bottom are attached. Nothing broken off. Unable to send pictures to show you. It is emt conduit throughout. Also they have a total of four neutrals with two of then attached to the receptacle and two blacks ( and 1 hot)  with a third one going to the hot receptacle. They loop it before with the hot and thought it would be best to add a new conductor from the wire nut.  the blue wires are pass through the box from one conduit to another. Most handy boxes in house (3.75x2x1.78).

Comment: @JimStewart i purchased two extenders which means i would have to disconnect everything including the conduits and add this. Is it worth it? It fits no problem. Like your other idea about putting 14 ga in the back of the receptacle. My problem is this isnt my only problem with wires, i would have to do another ten boxes. How in the world would inspectors pass this in the 70 when the home was built and when i bought it in 1986. That is why electrians no offense guys arent my favorite. I found already then mixing 14 and 12 ga wire which i corrected.

Comment: You should be able to slip the extender over the receptacle with the wires connected. If you are only using the extender to come out say 1/2 inch, then you can cut off the back of the extender if you have to to get it on. You should not have to disconnect the wires. There is nothing wrong with mixing 14 AWG and 12 AWG  wires as long as the breaker is sized for the smaller wire. Larry, I was only trying to head off a problem with box fill, not trying to get picky or raise a barrier for you. I thought you wrote that some of the receptacles were not working? Are you saying that they are?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58220/discussion-between-jim-stewart-and-larry-pinsky).

Comment: Yes it works perfectly and still does but i found a problem that might had been there for 40 yrs which affected the other receptacles. Though i didn't take a picture i used masking tape on each wire. But your right picture would had been better. Again tha k you for your kindness and thorough explanation.

Comment: Thank you all for truly trying to help. Will let this question remain unanswered.  I will ask around to find out exactly why? How can one wire shut off the remaining switches and receptacles with that circuit breaker on?  Planning to test  another receptacle from this sane circuit breaker to see if it also shuts down all with the circuit breaker on.

Comment: I tested two other receptacles from that circuit breaker. First removed the neutral-- the other switches/receptacles worked all perfect and the removing the hot from those two with the Neutral---other 18 receptacles/switches worked fine with the power on.  Again thank you all for trying. It is that neutral with the black mark on it is the one that shuts everything off on that breaker when breaker is on.  Jim thank you -- i tried. Will ask a couple of electricians on what causing it to shut off and will let this forum know so others wont have the same issue. This forum has been a. Miracle.

Comment: Larry, a white wire can be used as a hot and if so is supposed to be marked with black tape or otherwise marked black. You are calling it a neutral, but, if I understand you, when you connect it to true neutrals and turn on the breaker it immediately trips. This means it is a hot. Stop connecting it to neutrals. The black marked white must be feeding something. This is what I think but I am not an experienced electrician and have never worked on anything but my own house which is wired in NM. Unless someone here can help you, **I fully agree that it is time for you to call an electrician.**

Comment: The problem is that white neutral wire doesnt trip anything. When connected the receptacle worls perfectly. But when you remove tha white mark wire all switches/receptacles to that circuit goes off when the power is on. strange. As you saw there was only 5.3 voltage using a clamp meter connection.

Comment: No, i didnt try that capping which seems logical and probably might work. Will give it a try tomorrow. Excellent idea. No this was never a split receptacle either. But your suggestion is worth a try. Get back to you when i try it. Asking electricians not having them Come over yet. Im sure i can find a solution on what is truly transpiring.

Comment: Sorry three phase Ed. Wont happen again. Also the question was basically why does my white neutral shuts off all of my receptacles and switches to that circuit breaker when it is on?

Answer (score 1):

Larry, a white wire can be used as a hot and if so is supposed to be marked with black tape or otherwise marked black. You are calling it a neutral, but, if I understand your explanation, when you connect it to true neutrals and turn on the breaker it immediately trips. This means it is a hot.

Stop connecting it to neutrals. The black marked white must be feeding something. This is what I think, but I am not an experienced electrician and have never worked on anything but my own housen and it is wired in NM. Unless someone here can help you, **I fully agree that it is time for you to call an electrician.**

The only thing in my limited knowledge that I can imagine is that this black marked white is or was connected to a switch. This switch controlled a receptacle or half of the duplex receptacle. If the latter, the tab would have been broken and the other half powered directly. Do you have a switch near this box which seemingly doesn't do anything? Is it on? Even if the switch is off it may have been disconnected and the two wires connected together and the switch replaced. This would be contrary to code, but could have been done.

Does everything work if you just cap this black marked white wire? If so, just leave it capped and accept that you have an abandoned wire in the wall. If my suggestion is right, then one of the black wires goes to the same switch and it could also be disconnected with no loss of function.

Comment: "a white wire can be used as a hot". No, not in this case (wires smaller than 4Ga in conduit). If that white wire isn't a neutral, it's a code violation and it should be replaced with a wire of a correct color. https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/163727